# Yii 2 Multilingual Model Validation Errors Issue

Tags: validation, yii2, multilingual

I am using Yii 2 Basic.

For displaying error in any form for field email, it should say

**"Email cannot be blank"**

and in arabic

**" البريد الإلكتروني لا يمكن تركه فارغًا."**

How can I do that if I have 2 panels

- MemberPanel (where registered members can login)
- AdminPanel (where admin can login)

MemberPanel can either be in English or Arabic. (on member selection)

AdminPanel must be in English

Can anyone guide me in all steps that I would follow. Thanks

Comment: This should help - http://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/i18n-selecting-application-language/

Comment: Thanks @Bizley for the informative link ...